# Why does my EventStore Docker container stop when using the given command?

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, eventstoredb

I install and run EventStore with this command:

```
docker run --name eventstore-node -d -p 2113:2113 -p 1113:1113 eventstore/eventstore
```

the container stops when running

log file image: [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phwzl.jpg)

I did the comments [here](https://github.com/EventStore/EventStore/issues/2547) didn't help me

Answer (score 0):

It tells you what's wrong in the log. You either need to provide the certificates configuration, or the `insecure` option. If you want the embedded UI to work, you also need to enable AtomPub.

If you copy-paste the command [from the docs](https://developers.eventstore.com/server/v22.10/installation.html#run-with-docker), it will work.

```
docker run --name esdb-node -it -p 2113:2113 -p 1113:1113 \
    eventstore/eventstore:latest \
    --insecure \
    --run-projections=All \
    --enable-atom-pub-over-http
```

Comment: This command is not recognized at all in the command line
I have already done the documentation you suggested and it didn't help me.
Docker runs the hello world container properly and we make sure that the Docker installation on the system looks smooth.
I should also say that I tried to install sql server in docker and I encountered the same problem that the container stopped. May be useful for better guidance

Comment: What do you mean by "the command is not recognised"? Is if because you are on Windows and not using WSL, and the command prompt doesn't work with Linux-style line breaks? You can just remove the line breaks and all the backslash symbols.

Comment: I am not very familiar with Docker and I only went to it to set up an event store and I ran into a problem
I executed the commands that your suggested document gave in the command prompt and it gave me the following output  =>docker: invalid reference format.
See 'docker run --help'. 'eventstore' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.'--enable-external-tcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.